# How to make Quokka.js recognize local modules

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, quokka.js

I'm looking for a clear way to either require

`const MyModel = require("../../models/MyModel");`

or import

`import MyModel from "../../models/MyModel";`

local modules in a way that Quokka understands in ES6. Both approaches compile and do not throw errors on runtime. However, Quokka either says the require code has an "`Unexpected Identifier`" or ignores the import code line entirely.

Comment: I have a similar problem trying to import a module. `Cannot find module... at Function.Module._resolveFilename `

Answer (score 2):

**Quokka** supports module imports **only for pro version**. If you are ready to go, there might be additional configuration needed. You can configure inside the `package.json` file, the settings below:

```
"quokka" : {
    "babel" : {
        presets: ['env']
    }
 }
```

Also you are able to set it as global on `~/.quokka/config.json`